# How to index a tensor using arrays?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, slice

Suppose I have a 3D array (tensor)

```
print a.shape
(100, 100, 100)
```

and want to index its first axis using one array:

```
print i.shape
(20,)
```

and its last axis using another array

```
print j.shape
(30,)
```

My intent is to get a (20, 100, 30) array, for example, to be used in assignments like

```
a[?!, :, ?!] = b
```

However, I can't figure out how.

```
print a[i.reshape(20, 1, 1), :, j.reshape(1, 1, 30)].shape
(20, 1, 30, 100)

print a[i.reshape(20, 1, 1), :, j].shape
(20, 1, 30, 100)

print a[i.reshape(20, 1), :, j].shape
(20, 30, 100)

print a[i.reshape(20, 1, 1), j.reshape(1, 1, 30)].shape
(20, 1, 30, 100)
```

As I understand the "advanced indexing" rules, the first attempt should have worked, but I didn't even end up with a 3D array, and the full dimension (100) came at the end instead of the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :**  You can use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) for getting such meshes of indices and simply indexing into the input array must give you the desired output. Thus, an implementation would be like so -

```
a[np.ix_(i,np.arange(a.shape[1]),j)]
```

**Approach #2 :** Simpler way using broadcasted indexing -

```
a[i[:,None],:,j].swapaxes(1,2)
```

---

Verify with a sample case -

```
In [24]: a = np.random.randint(0,99,(5,3,5))

In [25]: i = np.random.randint(0,5,(2))

In [26]: j = np.random.randint(0,5,(2))

In [27]: a[i[0],:,j[0]]
Out[27]: array([15,  7, 74])

In [28]: a[i[0],:,j[1]]
Out[28]: array([32, 19, 85])

In [29]: a[i[1],:,j[0]]
Out[29]: array([76, 65, 96])

In [30]: a[i[1],:,j[1]]
Out[30]: array([54, 65, 66])

In [31]: a[np.ix_(i,np.arange(a.shape[1]),j)]
Out[31]: 
array([[[15, 32],
        [ 7, 19],
        [74, 85]],

       [[76, 54],
        [65, 65],
        [96, 66]]])

In [50]: a[i[:,None],:,j].swapaxes(1,2)
Out[50]: 
array([[[15, 32],
        [ 7, 19],
        [74, 85]],

       [[76, 54],
        [65, 65],
        [96, 66]]])
```

---

**Assigning values with the indexing**

For approach #1, it's just straight-forward -

```
a[np.ix_(i,np.arange(a.shape[1]),j)] = b
```

For approach #2, if `b` is a scalar, it should be straight-forward too -

```
a[i[:,None],:,j] = b
```

For approach #2 again, if you are assigning to a ndarray `b` of shape `(20,100,30)`, we need to swap axes of `b` before assigning, like so -

```
a[i[:,None],:,j] = np.swapaxes(b,1,2)
```

Comment: Approach 2 seems wrong: a[i[:,None],:,j].shape == (20, 30, 100)

Comment: @MaxB Yup, needed  a permute of dims. Updated code.

Comment: "swapaxes" can't be used on the left hand side of an assignment

Comment: @MaxB Could be an old version of NumPy causing that error. Try : `np.swapaxes(a[i[:,None],:,j],1,2)` instead.

Comment: Could be my Python version. The error is "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call". Approach 1 works though, it's just a little unsatisfying that one needs to create a temporary array.

Comment: @MaxB See if the added section on assigning works out for you.

Comment: It's strange that `swapaxes` is needed here. Is this a bug/misfeature in numpy?

Comment: @MaxB Agreed that it's not very intuitive, but from what I gathered, it seems all axes that are not "fancy-indexed", the ones with `colons :` are pushed back. Therefore, `np.ix_` makes more intuitive sense. One hybrid approach that could make more sense would be like : `a[i[:,None,None],np.arange(a.shape[1])[:,None],j] = b` as we are fancy-indexing all axes in this case. But yeah I don't have a good explanation on the seen behavior with a mix of colons and fancy indexing.